# exposing dto properties based on groups (user role) in NestJS

Tags: validation, serialization, nestjs, dto, role-base-authorization

I'm using `Prisma`, my schema has a table user where a user can have the role of a normal user or an admin.

I have an `editUserDto` that validates the incoming data during patch requests for the user.

I want to change the logic so that if the user role is `ADMIN`, the admin can only change the role of the user (so only the role will be exposed to the admin)

and if the user role is `USER`, only `fullname` and `phoneNumber` will be exposed

the following is `edit-user.dto.ts`:

```
import { Role } from '@prisma/client';
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsEmail, IsEnum, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';



export class EditUserDto {
  @IsString()
  @Expose({ groups: [Role.USER] })
  fullname: string;

  @IsString()
  @Expose({ groups: [Role.USER] })
  phoneNumber: string;

  @IsEnum(Role)
  @Expose({ groups: [Role.ADMIN] })
  role: Role;
}
```

`user.controller.ts`:

```
import {
  Body,
  ClassSerializerInterceptor,
  Controller,
  Get,
  Param,
  Patch,
  SerializeOptions,
  UploadedFile,
  UseGuards,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Role, User } from '@prisma/client';
import { GetUser } from '../auth/decorator';
import { JwtGuard } from '../auth/guard';
import { EditUserDto } from './dto';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Get('me')
  getMe(@GetUser() user: User) {
    return user;
  }

  @Patch('/:userId')
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor, FileInterceptor('file'))
  @SerializeOptions({ 
    groups: [Role.ADMIN],
  })
  editUser(
    @GetUser('id') requestingUserId: string,
    @Param('userId') userId,
    @Body() dto: EditUserDto,
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    return this.userService.editUser(userId, dto, requestingUserId, file);
  }
}
```

the code I have shown above acts a bit weird. when I make a request and provide the data for all properties, I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "fullname must be a string",
        "phoneNumber must be a string",
        "role must be a valid enum value"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

my 1st question: why would it complain that these values haven't been passed? if I comment out the expose decorator or pass an empty array, the data is accepted by the dto so I'm guessing the problem is related to `expose`.

my 2nd question: assuming that problem is resolved, how can I pass a dynamic group into the `SerializeOptions` based on the current user's role?

my 3rd question: is this the right approach? is there an entirely different way to do this?

appreciate any help I can get.
thanks in advance.